# Can't resolve 'react-router-dom ' in 'C:\Users\ferna\Desktop\Pixel\pixel_frontend\src' ... I tried npm install react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

App.js file

```
import React from 'react'
import {Routes, Route, useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from './components/Login';
import Home from './container/Home';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="/*" element={<Home />} />
    </Routes>
  )
}

export default App
```

Index.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom ';
import App from './App';
import './index.css'

const container = document.getElementById('app');
const root = createRoot(container);
root.render(<App />);
```

having error in react-router-dom module not found

i tried npm install react-router-dom --save

Comment: The `react-router-dom`  import in `index.js` is incorrect, there's a typo with an extra space at the end. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your index.js you have an extra space at the end of this line

```
  import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom ';
```

here it is corrected:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Comment: Just FYI, it is preferable to close questions caused by typos as they only help the OP and are not of any long-term value to future readers.